# Update inserted row with trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am inserting into table:

```
fruit:

fruit_id   |   name
-----------|----------
1          |  apple
----------------------
```

and I have another table :

```
basket:

basket_id   |   fruit_id   |   name
------------|--------------|-----------
345         |   1          |   apple
789         |   2          |   grape
```

when I insert:

```
insert into fruit (fruit_id) values (2)
```

I want to update the "name" column based on the name from the basket table.

I am trying to use this trigger to do this:

```
create trigger add_fruit_name
after insert
    on fruit
    for each row
DECLARE
BEGIN
    update fruit
    set (name) =  
    (select name from basket
    where :new.fruit_id = basket.fruit_id);
    commit;
END;
/
```

My error when I try to insert using this trigger is this:

```
table FRUIT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

any ideas?

Comment: You can't alter a table from inside a row based trigger associated with that table, without using an autonomous transaction. Use a before trigger, and set the value of the :new row column directly?

Comment: You are right, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mutating trigger means that the data changes on trigger firing, in your case, you're updating (DML operation) the same table, on insert (DML operation) into the same one, which means that the trigger won't see that possibly and thus the error + it has a commit in it, without this being in an AUTONOMOUS_TRANSATION (read more on that PRAGMA to understand it).
Now, as a general rule, triggers **should not commit**, unless they're in an autonomous transaction, this is done by declaring the above mentioned PRAGMA (only in extreme cases).
I would write the trigger like so:

```
create trigger add_fruit_name
before insert
    on fruit
    for each row
DECLARE
BEGIN
    select b.name
      into :new.name
      from basket b
     where b.fruit_id = :new.fruit_id;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      raise_application_error (-20001,'No fruit found in table basket for fruit_id: ' || to_char(:new.fruit_id));
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error (-20002, 'Trigger add_fruit_name raised an error' || SQLERRM);

END;
/
```

Another approach is to edit the function/procedure that inserts rows into the fruit table and make it update it appropriately.

A small, but important article to understand - [check this out](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm)!

Cheers

Comment: The trigger should be BEFORE INSERT. Your trigger won't compile: `ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type`